# Swift 3 UnsafePointer sqlite

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I use the below code to get a value from a recordset in sqlite:

```
let colSQL0 = sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)
let value = String(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>(colSQL0!))
```

that is working fine, but now in Swift 3 appears the following error getting the value:

```
error: 'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily
```

any suggestion? thank you in advance...

Comment: The referenced answer  was updated for Swift 3, hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that updated answer for Swift 3 helps me... in my case should like that: let value = String(cString: colSQL0!)